# How to get length of a nsstring in nsstring that is always 2 digits long?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am taking the length of a nsstring and converting it to nsstring. I need this last string  always 2 digits long, so for example word "hello"'s length in string would be "05" and not "5".

My code so far:

```
NSString *sth=@"hello";
NSMutableString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sth.length]; //string is "5" and not "05" that i need
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add .2 after % sign(similar as with floating numbers and decimal part).

```
    NSString *sth=@"hello";
    NSMutableString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d", sth.length];
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way if I understand your question correctly:

```
NSString *fish = @"Chips";
NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",[fish length]];
NSLog(@"Chips length is %@",length);
```

Produces:

```
2012-01-23 10:42:20.316 TestApp[222:707] Chips length is 05
```

The 02 means zero pad to length of 2.  You will probably want to check that the length of your string is less than 99 characters though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
NSMutableString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d", sth.length];
```